# iOS in-App purchase Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, air, in-app-purchase

I am developing a game for iOS with Adobe AIR, and i am looking to add the functionality of In-App purchase, social media and game center. So recently i have come to an understanding of what is Native Extensions means, they connect my AIR code to Apple iOS SDK library.

So the question is: Are those native extensions not offered by Adobe, so here the buying comes, lets say this one [**here**](http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/#iosiap).

So i have to buy this from milkman games, import the extension and call it from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe released a free ANE called the ProductStore with the Adobe Gaming SDK. You don't have to purchase the Milkman Games one.